# Modify linked SQL table name in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a SQL table linked in Access. I'd like to know how to change the linked table object to reference a different table with the same design but another name. For example, I link Table1 and create forms with it, and now need to change it to Table2.

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this.

- The table Description in Design View contains all the linked database and table information but it's not editable.
- Using the Linked Table Manager, I can change the database the table comes from, but the tables in both databases need to have the same name.
- I can create a query with `Select * From Table1` and change it to `Select * From Table2` to switch tables, but I don't want to use a workaround if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the linked table, and use [DoCmd.TransferDatabase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196455.aspx) to recreate the link with different names:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC", your_ODBC_String, acTable, _
    "schema.source_table", "target_table"
```

You can look up `your_ODBC_String` from existing linked tables.

Add the `StoreLogin:=True` parameter if needed.

Comment: Well, in a standard module into a public sub, I suggest. How to use it depends on whether this is a one-time operation, or regularly executed.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! For anyone who reads this answer in the future, I noticed there's a hierarchy with what a form will take as its RecordSource. It will take a new table with an identical name before it will take a renamed table. For example, if I have an Access table `Table1` and rename it to `TableA`, the form will switch to `TableA`. However, if I have `TableA` (originally Table1) and add a new table named `Table1`, the form will switch to the new `Table1`.